# Pandas: How to concatenate dataframes in the following manner?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I want to concatenate multiple dataframes into one dataframe. The manner I want the concatenation to happen is illustrated in the following example:

```
Input tables:
   A  B  C  D
0  x  p  2  4
1  y  q  3  5

   A  B  E  F
0  x  p  6  8
1  y  q  9  10

Output table:

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  x  p  2  4  6  8
1  y  q  3  5  9  10
```

I want to know if this can be done using the pandas.concat command. I know this can be done through the pd.merge command.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible by `pd.concat([df1.set_index(['A','B']), df2.set_index(['A','B'])])`

Comment: The Pandas website has great documentation for the pandas.concat function. The pandas.concat() page in particular has several examples using pandas.concat.

Comment: @David i read that page, it is very well documented but i couldn't find how to do this using pd.concat, they did it for pd.merge.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with list comprehension for `MultiIndex` and then [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

df = pd.concat([x.set_index(['A','B']) for x in dfs], axis=1)
```